# VBA Excel - Find value and copy corresponding cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with several sheets.  The Sheet1 acts as a sort of summary of action items based on the info we enter into the other sheets.

In Sheet1, Column A is titled Tester and under that we are manually entering the defect numbers that group needs to review.

In Sheet2, we have a list of all the defects. Each defect has its own row.
Column A has all the unique defect numbers (e.g., Defect001, Defect002, Defect003).

In Column B we have a dropdown list with all the groups a defect could be assigned to (e.g., Tester, Developer, Client).

Other columns have the various details, severity, SLA times, etc. for the defect.

Right now, we enter all the info into Sheet2 and then go to Sheet1 and enter the defect numbers under the team that needs to work them.

I want to remove the manual component of all this.  Instead, I want the defects entered in Sheet2 to automatically appear under their corresponding group on Sheet1.

So, on Sheet2, I have a button tied to a macro which updates various fields in the Workbook.

I want to add to that macro some functionality that will do the following:

- Look at Sheet 2, Column B
- For each row that has a value of Tester in Column B, go to the corresponding cell in Column A to get the defect number.
- Back in Sheet 1 under the Tester column (Column A), I want each defect to be listed.

Therefore, if Sheet2 has Defect001, Defect003, and Defect005 that were all assigned to the Tester group, those values would appear in one cell under the Tester column in Sheet1.

Since some folks think I am asking them to do all the work for me, let me clarify that I am not.  I just need a starting point...something to get me going in the right direction.  I appreciate any code or links that would get me started down the right path.

Let me know if I need to provide more detail or information.

Thanks for all your help.

==============

As requested, here are the code snipits I have tried so far:

```
For i = 1 To 5000
If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 12).Value = "Tester" Then
MsgBox "This Works"
End If
Next i
```

And I looked into trying to figure out how to call the info via a pivot:

```
Sub ListAllItemObjects()
For Each pvt In ActiveSheet.PivotTables
For Each fld In pvt.PivotFields
For Each itm In fld.PivotItems
MsgBox itm
Next itm
Next fld
Next pvt
End Sub
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Wish I could...I haven't really figured out how.  I've come up with a couple pieces of things that only partially work, but nothing that would encompass everything I want to do.

Comment: You should include the pieces in your post because now it looks like you're just asking people to code and SO isn't a coding service. Besides, what you want to do isn't terribly difficult. You should be able to search related posts here on SO and combine them to fit your needs.

Comment: Thank you for the unhelpful response.  I wasn't asking for anyone to code something for me nor am I treating this as a coding service.  I just need to be pointed in the right direction.  If the code is so easy, feel free to provide it or provide some place I can start from.  If there are so many posts related to my conundrum, please link to them.

Comment: Awesome findwindow.  That really helps.  Oh wait...I just realized I have no idea what to search for to get those 1899 results.  I have searched and searched and searched, but I've had no luck figuring it out.  I've spent all morning trying to unravel this puzzle with my admittedly limited skills.  I come here for help and the only "help" I get is someone making accusations and telling me that "the results are out there if you only knew what to search for".

Comment: lol I can't even tell if you're trolling now. No idea? All morning? I am hesitant to answer because I don't want to make you feel stupid but suppose you need to replace spark plugs for your car, what would you search? If you need to find then copy... Look, I have work to do but if I am free tomorrow, I see if I can code you something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came up with a solution.  Probably not the best.  As FindWindow was so helpful to point out, I'm not an expert in VBA.

This will probably need some further adjustment to do everything I want, but it works well enough for now.

So to find the values I wanted that correspond to any row with Tester in Column B:

```
Sub UpdateStatusSummary()


For i = 1 To 5000
For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2)
      If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = "Tester" Then
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 10).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value

    End If
Next
Next i

End Sub
```

This Sub (which will be changed to a Private Sub) is called with a button/graphic that has the Sub assigned to it.

To get the values from the Data sheet into one cell back on Sheet1, I went with this:

```
Function csvRange(myRange As Range)
Dim csvRangeOutput
For Each entry In myRange
    If Not IsEmpty(entry.Value) Then
        csvRangeOutput = csvRangeOutput & entry.Value & ","
    End If
Next
csvRange = Left(csvRangeOutput, Len(csvRangeOutput) - 1) 

End Function
```

Use =csvRange(Data!J2:J5000) in the cell you want the comma separated values from the Data sheet to go in.

Could and probably will be better after I play with it for a while.  If I make any significant breakthroughs or changes, I'll be sure to post them.

If anyone has any feedback or better methods, I would greatly appreciate the **constructive** criticism.